# Transducers versus Sensors - applied to mobile robotics

Tags: sensor, robotics, transducer

I am doing some basic research for an upcoming personal project, learning everything I can relate to mobile robotics. This project will be used for my personal portfolio.

So, my questions are very specific, relate to mobile robotics.

1. Definition of transducers, because sometimes I am confused with sensors, is hard for me, to provide a clear cut example to my colleagues. What I know is the fact the transducers convert one form of energy to another form (wiki definition and Handbook of Robotics (2008, Springer), a close example are: a photovoltaic cell, where to acquire solar radiation converting into electric energy. What applications do we have applying to mobile robotics? Is there a way to know, when I handle a device, knowing what sensors and transducers because I know there are some sensors, were worked for both ways.
2. Daily life applications of transducers that can be a model of reference and mental reference.

Comment: I would say that this question is rather broad and you are asking us to gather information for you. I would suggest you to focus on the specific function of your mobile robotics unit and determine what it should sense, then, maybe someone will suggest a suitable sensor/transducer for your application.

Comment: This *Sensors vs Transducers* question comes up once in a while.  I wrote a [general answer](https://makersconfidential.blogspot.com/2015/04/difference-between-sensors-and-transducers.html) last year.

Comment: Hi, I am aware that my question is broad, I didn't ask for you gather any information, I am simply asked for examples, that all. 

For now, I am focusing on the temperature sensor, the application context is detecting the thermal source, however, I want to avoid some external influences, like a human thermal source and for the case of overlapping thermal source. As I clearly stated I am having problems with definitions, which reflect on my research. 

This project is self-taught, so forgive me if my intention was not clear enough. 

Thank you for you answer, I am very grateful.

Comment: Mr. Alexeev, I am self-taught engineering, I don´t have money to go to college again, despite having BA in History. 

I am grateful for your link and your answer.

Comment: Edit: Mr. Alexeev after careful reading, can I think the converter DC/AC and vice versa, as transducers? Your "mercenary" way since AC/DC the output is digital so that can be a transducer but not DC/AC because the output is analogic?

Answer (score 1):

A transducer, by definition, converts one form of energy into another form of energy.  In our context, we're often turning some form of kinetic energy into electrical energy, but it could go the other way, like in a loudspeaker.

A sensor senses something.

A sensor can be a transducer and a transducer can be a sensor.